# Finding Big-O for a Rabin-Miller test

Tags: java, big-o

So I'm trying to find out what Big-O is for a Rabin-Miller test and I've done some research on it but I can't really find a good explanation for it. The thing that confuses me the most is this part:

```
while( !isPrime(n)){
n = new BigInteger(bit, new Random());
}
```

This is a piece of my main program where I keep generating a new number until I find a prime and then it exits the loop. How can I estimate Big-O when I don't know how many times the while loop will run?

Comment: The point is to understand the Rabin-Miller logic to know how to calculate the number of worst-case iterations for a particular `n` value. Then multiply that with the Big-O of `isPrime`. Are you asking us how Rabin-Miller works? This is not a teaching site, so I hope not, given that you should be able to find that information on the web, e.g. on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). *Hint: There's an entire section on "Computational complexity" on page wikipedia page.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when calculating the Big-O, there are three things to do

1. find the best case
2. find the worst case
   and
3. find the average case.

In this instance, the worst case Big-O would clearly be O(infinity), which will be achieved in the highly unlikely case that n is initially not a prime number, and all the newly calculated instances of n are also never going to be prime numbers.

The best case Big-O would be the same as the Big-O of your isPrime() method. This is because the best case would be when n is initially a prime number, which will cause the while loop to never be executed at all. One thing to note is that your while-loop condition does two things : check if a boolean value is true, and calls the `isPrime()` method. So to find the Big-O, one must multiply the Big-O of the `isPrime()` method by the Big-O of the boolean being checked. The Big-O of the boolean being checked is O(1). Therefore, your best case will be the same as the Big-O of your isPrime() method, as 1*x = x. I do not know how wrote your isPrime() method, so cannot tell you the best-case Big-O.

The average case however, is harder to find here because you're dealing with random numbers. Since we deal with random numbers, the average case can be calculated using something called [expected analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Expected_number_of_failures_before_the_first_success) In order to do this however, we need to know the range of the random numbers. The java api says that the [bigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-java.util.Random-) constructor that you're using calculates random numbers within the range of 0 and 2^bit-1, inclusive.(Positive numbers only). Since I don't know what the value of `bit` in your code, I cannot give you the average case, but hope that you'll be able to calculate that yourself.

If you have any questions just ask!